# How to test database code after changing column data types?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, unit-testing

I have a database containing lots of logic and I have to maintain it. I need a way to know that everything at least works after changing something.

For example I would like to know if all the stored procedures and triggers still work after changing the type of a column.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear: are you asking how to test your database code (I assume you mean stored procedures/functions?) after changing the data type of a table column? Or how to find all references to the changed object? In the first case you're asking about testing, in the second you're asking about identifying dependencies.

Comment: @Pondfile: I'm asking about testing (compiling), sorry if it was not clear enought.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I updated the question to make it clearer that you're asking about testing. The short answer is that you need to develop a set of test scripts; unfortunately the tools for testing database code are generally not as well developed as for other types of code, but there are many [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql-server+unit+test) on this site about it, perhaps you can get some ideas from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through all [procedures, functions etc and invoke them in TSQL](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/checking-ms-sql-server-stored-procedures/), or run my [utility checktsql](http://devio.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/checking-ms-sql-server-objects/) (WinForms app).

However I did not analyze how to check triggers. (How could I forget?)

Comment: When we will have the version with trigger check? I'm planning to incorporate your tool to our set of common applications :)

Comment: Anyway I was thinking on something like an ALTER procedure without modifications to see if the command succeeds or not.

Comment: Triggers are not trivial. Remember you can only invoke them trough INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE. This means your data (Ins, Upd) needs to make it through any checks (non-identity columns, CHECK & FK constraints, UNIQUE indexes and constraints) defined, or records level checks for referential integrity in case (Del)

Comment: to test their correctness you don't need to execute them, you just need to execute an ALTER with the actual code. As far as I know if there is something wrong in the TRIGGER (like a wrong column name or type) the ALTER won't succeed. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at [tSQLt ( unit testing for TSQL)](http://tsqlt.org/). 
Using this, you can check functionality against estimated results.

Comment: That sounds great, anyway I'm not at the point of testing functionality. I'll be happy just knowing that code compiles.